# Generic error: type ... is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, generics

Ok. Let's say I have following small Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void interfaceMethod();
}
```

and a class which implements this interface:

```
public class GenericsTest implements MyInterface {
  @Override
  public void interfaceMethod() {
    // do something
  }
}
```

That's simple!

Now I have also another class which use a generic type `<T extends MyInterface>`:

```
public class AnotherClass<T extends MyInterface> {
  public void doSomethingWith(T obj) {
    System.out.println(obj.toString());
  }
}
```

And now the point which I don't understand. If I want call the AnotherClass.doSomethingWith(T) method like in the following code snippet (**this class is wrong; please see my edit below**):

```
public class ClassWithError {
  public ClassWithError(AnotherClass<? extends MyInterface> another) {
    another.doSomethingWith(another);
  }
}
```

I get following error:

```
The method doSomethingWith(capture#1-of ? extends MyInterface) in the type 
AnotherClass<capture#1-of ? extends MyInterface> is not applicable for the 
arguments (AnotherClass<capture#2-of ? extends MyInterface>)
```

Why That?

**EDIT**

Ohhhh nooo! My sample is wrong! ... grrrrrr ... SORRY!!

The ClassWithError must be right:

```
public class ClassWithError {
  public ClassWithError(AnotherClass<? extends MyInterface> another, GenericsTest test) {
    another.doSomethingWith(test);
  }
}
```

And then the error is:

```
The method doSomethingWith(capture#1-of ? extends MyInterface) in the type 
AnotherClass<capture#1-of ? extends MyInterface> is not applicable for the 
arguments (GenericsTest)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AnotherClass#doSomethingWith` is waiting for a parameter of type `T`, i.e. a subtype of `MyInterface`. In `ClassWithError`, you're passing an instance of `AnotherClass`, which does not fulfil this contract.

Either change `doSomethingWith` signature to (example):

```
public void doSomethingWith(AnotherClass<?> obj)
```

Or change body of `ClassWithError` to (example):

```
public ClassWithError(AnotherClass<GenericsTest> another) {
    GenericsTest instance = /* ... */;
    another.doSomethingWith(instance);
}
```

**EDIT**

With your new snippet, parameterizing your constructor could be a generic solution:

```
public class ClassWithError {
    public <T extends MyInterface> ClassWithError(AnotherClass<T> another, T test) {
        another.doSomethingWith(test);
    }
}
```

If you need to be sure `T` is a `GenericsTest`, then use:

```
public class ClassWithError {
    public <T extends GenericsTest> ClassWithError(AnotherClass<T> another, T test) {
        another.doSomethingWith(test);
    }
}
```

Or even simply:

```
public class ClassWithError {
    public ClassWithError(AnotherClass<GenericsTest> another, GenericsTest test) {
        another.doSomethingWith(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course! My sample was wrong. I have correct this.

Comment: Your first code snippet is what I want. Not really good readable for a human, but that's it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You attempted to use an upper bound generic type outside the scope of a generic type declaration. It's a little difficult to explain without seeing it and it's possible my terminology may be a bit off.

How would the compiler know what generic type `AnotherClass<? extends MyInterface>` actually is?

```
public class ClassWithError {
    public ClassWithError(AnotherClass<? extends MyInterface> another, GenericsTest test) {
        another.doSomethingWith(test);
    }
}
```

You have to capture that generic type somewhere, or specify it explicitly.

Either:

```
public class ClassWithError<T extends MyInterface> {
    public ClassWithError(AnotherClass<T> another, GenericsTest test) {
      another.doSomethingWith(test);
    }
}
```

or

```
public class ClassWithError {
    public ClassWithError(AnotherClass<MyInterface> another, GenericsTest test) {
        another.doSomethingWith(test);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please change your AnotherClass like below code.

```
public class AnotherClass<T extends MyInterfacee> {
  public void doSomethingWith(AnotherClass<? extends MyInterfacee> another) {
    System.out.println(another.toString());
  }
}
```

thanks.